# Crystmet or alternative metals/alloys/intermetallics powder diffraction database

Tags: crystallography

Does anyone know what happened to Crystmet, the metals structure database? The website seems to have disappeared.

Is there any way to access the database or is there a recommended powder diffraction database for metals/alloys/intermetallics that goes beyond PDF or ICDD? I would like to have access to CIF files for relatively uncommon non-stoichiometric intermetallics.

Comment: Our lab would use the Fink Index to search XRD patterns , intermetallics, corrosion products,etc. . It was a very large collection  of patterns in  print, not computer.

Comment: NIST offers a metals/alloys/intermetallics database but it has been offline and not available for sale for months due to updating. I have tried contacting NIST many times about updates with no reply.